# Complete lines after ''|" character with specific data from line above/below

Tags: bash, shell, dataset

I have a dataset with that looks similar to the below.

And I need to complete every line after the '|' with the same value of the line before/after this specific line where the value before "|" matches the actual line.

I would really appreciate if this could be done with bash/shell script or maybe excel.

```
10166_101|  
10166_101|50  
10296_5|  
10296_5|50  
10484_5|20  
10484_5|  
10692_7|  
10692_7|10  
10742_102|  
10742_102|100  
10742_102|  
10767_13|  
10767_13|30  
10793_9|  
10793_9|50  
10863_8|40  
10863_8|  
10887_3|  
10887_3|40  
10929_2|24  
11004_2|10  
11151_5|  
11151_5|20  
11212_21|80  
11447_6|30  
11486_9|  
11486_9|80  
11510_105|20  
11510_105|  
11610_3|  
11610_3|10  
11635_7|20  
11635_7|
```

So the data would look like this:

```
10166_101|50  
10166_101|50  
10296_5|50  
10296_5|50  
10484_5|20  
10484_5|20  
10692_7|10  
10692_7|10  
10742_102|100  
10742_102|100  
10742_102|100  
10767_13|30  
10767_13|30  
10793_9|50  
10793_9|50  
10863_8|40  
10863_8|40  
10887_3|40  
10887_3|40  
10929_2|24  
11004_2|10  
11151_5|20  
11151_5|20  
11212_21|80  
11447_6|30  
11486_9|80  
11486_9|80  
11510_105|20  
11510_105|20  
11610_3|10  
11610_3|10  
11635_7|20  
11635_7|20
```

Comment: In the future, please reduce the amount of sample data to the minimum number of lines that illustrate the problem you're trying to solve AND include you best attempt to code a solution. Pease read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/sh
sort --reverse inputfile > /tmp/reversedinput
awk -F\|   '$0=="" {next}
            $2!="" {line=$0;print line}
            $2=="" {print line;}' /tmp/reversedinput > /tmp/reversedoutput
sort /tmp/reversedoutput > outputfile
```

---

### How does it work?

This sorts your `inputfile` reversely, so that it becomes `/tmp/reversedinput`:

```
11635_7|20
11635_7|
11610_3|10
11610_3|
11510_105|20
11510_105|
...
```

Now, read the file line by line (starting from the top) and, if the line on the current iteration has nothing after the pipe char, just replace it by the line above. That's what the `awk` fragment is doing. So you get `/tmp/reversedoutput`.

Finally, just sort it back in the correct order and you get `outputfile`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this awk script:

```
awk -F"|" -v OFS="|" '
NR == FNR { if ($2) values[$1] = $2 ;  next } 
{ print $1 , values[$1] }
' $1 $1
```

Above, $1 is considered the parameter to the script - it should be the filename of your input file.  I pass the file to awk twice `$1 $1` to have awk parse the file twice.  The first time awk reads the file, the expression `NR == FNR` is true.  That is, the current record number (NR) is the same as the record number in the current file.  Anyway,  we are just remembering the values in the values hash.
Awk goes through the file one more time, printing each line with the value associated with it.

Answer (score 0):

This excel function will solve the problem, simply paste the "input" into cell A2 and then use this function in Cell B2, then fill down till you reach B34 (in this case).

```
 =IF(LEN(A2)=FIND("|",A2),
      IF(MID(A2,1,FIND("|",A2))=IFERROR(MID(A1,1,FIND("|",A1)),""),
          MID(A2,1,FIND("|",A2))&MID(A1,FIND("|",A1)+1,99),
          IF(MID(A2,1,FIND("|",A2))=MID(A3,1,FIND("|",A3)),
               MID(A2,1,FIND("|",A2))&MID(A3,FIND("|",A3)+1,99),
               A2)),
     A2)
```

how does it work?

It first checks if the string needs modification:

```
LEN(A2)=FIND("|",A2)
```

if it does, then it compares the first half of the string to the prior row:

```
IF(MID(A2,1,FIND("|",A2))=IFERROR(MID(A1,1,FIND("|",A1)),"")`
```

Note: the "IFERROR" is to handle the first row case because the MID function will return #Value

If it matches, then it merges the current string first half, with the prior string second half (this is probably overkill since the 2 rows should be identical).

```
MID(A2,1,FIND("|",A2))&MID(A1,FIND("|",A1)+1,99)
```

output:

```
10166_101|50
10166_101|50
10296_5|50
10296_5|50
10484_5|20
10484_5|20
10692_7|10
10692_7|10
10742_102|100
10742_102|100
10742_102|100
10767_13|30
10767_13|30
10793_9|50
10793_9|50
10863_8|40
10863_8|40
10887_3|40
10887_3|40
10929_2|24
11004_2|10
11151_5|20
11151_5|20
11212_21|80
11447_6|30
11486_9|80
11486_9|80
11510_105|20
11510_105|20
11610_3|10
11610_3|10
11635_7|20
11635_7|20
```